# Why are anaphonic antonyms regarded as chance by many linguistic historians

Tags: historical-linguistics

Why are anaphonic antonyms regarded as chance by many linguistic historians, if this could be regarded as an Ancient mnemonic method of creating a logical and easy inverted spelling of antonyms?

Anaphone I would define as “A word that spelled backwards shows an antonym” (I regard near anaphones (the spelling backwards is nearly identical) as valid too if the antonymous relation exists in context.

Compare:
Growth/groot/Gross versus:
Dwarf/Dwerg/Zwerg

If we would not regard this as chance, what could we call such a phenomenon?

To make it a bit more complex:
Compare:
Cloud/de wolk versus:
Claw/walk
Soul versus sole (of the shoe)
What do we call such phenomenon if the relation is not antonymous, but contains an identical root (in the example the same root can be found in the word ‘ciel’ which shows an antonymous relation to ‘leg’ and ‘lig’ but the root is used in different contexts.

I could invent ‘antocrypt’ but some brilliant mind must have found a name for this already...?

Comment: ......so Frawd is the same as Growth?

Comment: If the German and Dutch words for dwarf end with a ‘g’, I assume that the English spelling of ‘f’ is the odd one. Same goes for the Dutch and German ‘e’ where English has ‘a’. So ‘Frawd’ doesn’t fit, but ‘grewd’ and ‘grewz’ show phonetic similarities with ‘growth’ and groot/Gross (large/big). But the question is not about the example, but about terminology. If you have an answer, I would like to hear it. I am not interested in mockery, which I hope was not your intention.

Comment: I think you're just finding coincidental similarities between words and some nearish-antonyms which happen to have a vaguely similar but reversed spelling. If you allow sufficient latitude in meaning and spelling then you're going to find lots of these.

Comment: What if these are not coincidences but a logical way of our brains to reverse word roots (the most initial spoken words with meaning)? It would explain how fall (hawa-elohi meaning sky up) in the sense of where the person came from; falling down, can also be seen inverted as elohi-hawa (eleve/elevate/lift) meaning ‘up-sky’ an inverted direction and an inverted compound of the same roots; fall and elevate. By the way I use existing or Ancient Semitic words ‘elohi’ or אֵל עַל (also meaning god) and ‘hawa’ (sky).

Comment: Have you heard of the "Birthday Paradox" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem ? Basically, if you have only 23 people, it is *more likely than not* that two people share a birthday. It's complete chance, and not the result of parents secretly conspiring to have babies at the same moment. With thousands of basic words from multiple languages, it will be surprising if you *cannot* find pairs that (very roughly) sound reverse of each other with related meanings.

Comment: Challenge excepted. Pick an Ancient word of 2 or more syllables. The method will proof itself

Comment: I'm not sure we understood each other. I'm saying that it's *completely normal* to be able to find words that look like reverse of each other, and the best explanation is simple chance. I'm not sure what you are trying to "prove" by showing yet another example.

Comment: No Jick, you don’t. You gave a probability condition comparisson. If you say this is normal, please give is linguistic proof for this assumption. You could formulate an answer to the question as well, but all it is right now is an unfounded assumption in comments.

Comment: Regarding my Walk/wolk vs Claw/cloud example, I’d like to show you why this is not chance; leg vs ciel (the leg is lifted towards the sky (ciel); foot/podo/voet/pied/Fuss vs pt (Ancient Egyptian word for sky); been/Bein (Dutch/German leg) vs nebo (Russian word for sky); fall/val vs lauf/loop (walk); sky vs ski (attached to the feet); sky vs skate (again attached to the feet).           And the connection in meaning between legs and sky expends itself in other languages to another aspect of the sky to movement; Icelandic himinn meaning sky contains the roots that also form the word animation.

Comment: Animates vs stamina; anime (spirit in Latin) shows a connection to life not motion. This meaning is shared also in laufen (to walk) and leven/leben (to live) which is logical because if you live you move and breathe and these ideas are therefor found with the same roots in all the examples. So here is a birthday party where everyone was born on a Christmas day. Chance? Don’t make me laugh... 

Comment: Nebo (Russian sky) is the anagram of German oben (above). Ancient Egyptian pt (sky) versus ‘top’ or ‘tip’. Mind that mountain contains the same roots as animation. Hemel/Himmel (sky in Dutch and German) vs Chj-m-3lohj life from up high: החיים מלמעלה /hchjjm mlm3lh

Comment: So if two words have a rather similar spelling and a similar or antonymous meaning in different contexts, One could make a case that this is no chance but proof of use of the same roots in a different phrase order both compounded to words resulting in these spelling similarities.

Comment: Breathes vs sterben/sterven (to die); the breath of life at birth goes in where it goes out when we die. Die and eat are antonyms.

Comment: I know this is rather condescending... but have you heard of "Burden of Proof"? You are the one proposing extremely unlikely connections, and it's your responsibility to back your argument, not mine (or anyone else's) to refute it. Bringing more and more poorly fitting examples will not persuade anybody, because it's *not established* that any of them actually means anything.

Comment: No problem. For the burden of proof, you would have to wait for publication of the book I am working on. The historical linguistic method of tracking words back to the Greek equivalent in many cases is overrated. Because Greek was the first European language that was written does not mean other European words originate from that Greek word. If intentionally in scientific terminologies, that is a reasonable and logic explanation. In all other cases it is speculative to say the least. Word roots transcend the demarcated established etymologies as they are, which are a card house ready to fall.

Comment: But this is meant generally. I praise anyone in the community, opening up to learn about the pro’s and cons of this method. We are all responsible for the best answer possible and the current methods in etymology are based on Eurocentrism and are too narrow a view on linguistics. And because it is too simple, too many questions stay unanswered. I wish linguistics to ‘go forth by day’.

Answer (score 6):

There are some that aren't chance! For example, an *emordnilap* is a word that gains a new meaning when it's written backward; the term was coined by flipping the existing word "palindrome" (a word that has the same meaning when written backward). Or in electrical engineering, the unit of conductance is the *mho* (the unit of *resistance* being the "ohm"). The technical term for these is *ananyms*.

However, most of these examples are fairly straightforward. Anyone who sees the word "emordnilap" with its  will know it's not an inherited English word, and probably look for deeper meaning.

All of the ananyms I know of come from languages that already have a writing system. Written language requires breaking words up into units which you can then rearrange freely, but this isn't at all an obvious step for people who don't write. For example, ananyms in Japanese and Korean tend to reverse the *syllables* instead of the phonemes, while the English example *emordnilap* would be pronounced something like /ə.ˈmord.nɪ.læp/ rather than /mwoɹd.nɪl.ˈæp/.

Another way to think of this is: what does it mean to reverse a word? Until we had record players we couldn't actually reverse the waveform; a human vocal tract certainly can't. Reversing the phones? That requires a clear way to draw a line between phones, which even with modern spectrograms we can't do. Reversing the phonemes? If you asked a person on the street to reverse the sounds in the word "pineapple", they most likely wouldn't be able to do it: at best they'd write down the word backward and repronounce it according to English spelling rules. Even in your examples, you're relying on the spelling rather than the pronunciation.

TL;DR: Flipping words around simply doesn't seem to be part of human language; we simply don't have a mechanism for it (unlike, say, reduplication, which people can do trivially). As such, we don't see any examples of ananyms until the origin of writing—and even then, they tend not to really catch on.

Comment: There are many examples within languages and also between different language families. Could this phenomenon never been : stand vs dance; fall vs lauf/leap; atmen (to breathe) vs mut (Arabic death);              Also near homophones; seat/stehe (stand).    Not just antonyms but also concepts like ‘light’ and ‘ciel’. I don’t base my find on spelling but on rots and roots can be inverted to express an antonym in some cases. So it would not be a word invertion. It would be a method of understanding what compounded to a word and reverse that phrase.